# Microsoft Graph API - User Delta Query Challenges

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

User Delta - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta

1. **Question**: Is it possible to get manager as part of user delta during every call even if there is no manager update
   **Observations**:

   a) $select=accountEnabled,ageGroup,manager,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName,
   userType

   b) Prefer: return=minimal is NOT used and it is
   returning all attributes mentioned in $select other than manager
   c) Currently User delta query returns manager only if it is update
2. **Question:** As there is limited support for $filter in user delta (only for id and that too with 50 objects), is there any other way
   to pass filter to delta to retreive updates for the filter used in
   ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@org.com')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,%27@org.com%27))

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question I can see it is working for me it is also returning the manager values event if request header is not set to Prefer: return=minimal
[Result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3SVN.png)

As for the second question i think as of filter only supports only for ID ,This feature is currently not available , if you want this feature to be there , you can raise a feature request - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform .

Comment: Thank you for the response on the second question. For the first question, can you please confirm if you are receiving manager data as part of delta response even when there is no manager update for the user. 

In my case I am receiving manager in delta response provided if there is a change in manager value. Otherwise it is not coming up.

Comment: Yes I have checked it, I am receiving manager data as part of delta response even when there is no manager update for the user.

Comment: For some reasons, even after trying various combinations it did not work for me. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta/?$select=accountEnabled,ageGroup,manager,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName, userType

Please let me know if anything you see missing. Manager data comes only if there is update. Any other property or setting?

Comment: Can you please share the Request ID and the timestamp when you are running the query and also please share the output screenshot